# Converter parameter "values" is null when converter is used after DataGrid has been scrolled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, converters

I have a DataGrid and a few Checkboxes that act as filters for the visibility of certain rows in the DataGrid. This works perfectly until the DataGrid is scrolled; if you try to filter the DataGrid through checking one of the Checkboxes then the converter that handles the logic for the filtering throws an exception, as the values parameter in the converter are now null.

I don't understand why this works at first but breaks afterwards. **Below is the xaml, and an example converter.**

***CONVERTER***

```
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //var softwareModel = (SoftwareModel)values[0];
        //var checkBox = (CheckBox)values[1];

        SoftwareModel softwareModel = values[0] as SoftwareModel;
        CheckBox checkBox = values[1] as CheckBox;

        if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            foreach (var missingSoftwareItem in SharedClass.requiredSoftwareMissingOC) // for each missing software
            {
                if (SharedClass.SoftwareModelComparitor(softwareModel, missingSoftwareItem)) // if missing == total
                {
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

***XAML***

```
<UserControl x:Class="NIThirdPartySoftwareChecker.Views.SoftwareChecksView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NIThirdPartySoftwareChecker.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SoftwareListContainsToDataGridRowStyleConverter x:Key="SoftwareListContainsToDataGridRowStyleConverter"/>
    <local:RequiredInstalledSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="RequiredInstalledSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter"/>
    <local:RequiredMissingSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="RequiredMissingSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter"/>
    <local:UnrequiredSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="UnrequiredSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" 
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SoftwareListContainsToDataGridRowStyleConverter}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chbx_hideUnrequiredSoftware, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnrequiredSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="."/>
                            <Binding ElementName="chbx_hideUnrequiredSoftware"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chbx_hideRequiredInstalledSoftware, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RequiredInstalledSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="."/>
                            <Binding ElementName="chbx_hideRequiredInstalledSoftware"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chbx_hideRequiredMissingSoftware, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RequiredMissingSoftwareToVisibiltyConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="."/>
                            <Binding ElementName="chbx_hideRequiredMissingSoftware"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="totalSoftwareCollectionViewSource" 
                          Source="{Binding TotalSoftwareOC}" 
                          CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource UI.BorderInnerStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                        Margin="5">

                <Label Content="Filters"
                       Margin="5"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                <CheckBox x:Name="chbx_hideUnrequiredSoftware" 
                          Content="Hide unrequired software" 
                          Foreground="White"
                          IsChecked="{Binding UnrequiredSoftwareIsChecked}"/>

                <CheckBox x:Name="chbx_hideRequiredInstalledSoftware" 
                          Content="Hide required installed software" 
                          Foreground="Green"
                          IsChecked="{Binding RequiredInstalledSoftwareIsChecked}"/>

                <CheckBox x:Name="chbx_hideRequiredMissingSoftware" 
                          Content="Hide required missing software" 
                          Foreground="Red"
                          IsChecked="{Binding RequiredMissingSoftwareIsChecked}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="5"
                   Content="Total software" 
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Margin="5"
                      RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}" 
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      RowHeight="20"
                      MinRowHeight="0"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      HeadersVisibility="Column"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource totalSoftwareCollectionViewSource}}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SoftwareSelectedRow}">

                <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                  Command="{Binding DataGridRowDoubleClickCommand}" />
                </DataGrid.InputBindings>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" 
                                        Header="Name"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Version}" 
                                        Header="Version"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just a note, since you seemingly replaced `(SoftwareModel)values[0]` by `values[0] as SoftwareModel`. Do not use the `as` operator without checking its result for `null`. If `values[0]` is not a SoftwareModel, the cast operation would correctly throw an InvalidCastException, while `as` would return null and give you a subsequent unexpected `NullReferenceException`.